# Symfony authentication always say Anonymous

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

In a new project with Symfony 4.4, I try to create a login page but the Symfony's toolbar always says that the current user is Anonymous and `$this->getUser()` always returns `null`:

security.yaml

```yaml
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_TECHNIQUE, ROLE_PRODUCTION, ROLE_COMMERCIAL, ROLE_CONSULTATION, ROLE_POLISSAGE]
        ROLE_TECHNIQUE: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_PRODUCTION: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_COMMERCIAL: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_CONSULTATION: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_POLISSAGE: ROLE_USER
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
          algorithm: auto
    providers:
        users:
            entity:
                class: 'App\Entity\User'
                property: username
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: lazy
            provider: users
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\UserAuthenticator
            logout:
                path: logout
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
         - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

App\Entity\User:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    public function __construct($username = NULL, $password = NULL, $roles = [])
    {
        $this->setUsername($username);
        $this->setPassword($password);
        $this->setRoles($roles);
    }

    /**
     * @var integer|null
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string[]
     * @ORM\Column(type="json")
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string The hashed password
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $salt;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @return int|null
     */
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int|null $id
     */
    public function setId(?int $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string[]
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    /**
     * @param string[] $roles
     */
    public function setRoles(array $roles): void
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $password
     */
    public function setPassword(string $password): void
    {
        $this->password = $password;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return $this->salt;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $salt
     */
    public function setSalt($salt): void
    {
        $this->salt = $salt;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $username
     */
    public function setUsername($username): void
    {
        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        $this->password = NULL;
    }
}
```

The Security controller:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
         if ($this->getUser()) {
             return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
         }

        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();
        return $this->render('auth/login.html.twig', ['last_username' => $lastUsername, 'error' => $error]);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {
    }
}
```

and the login template:

```html
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Connexion{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12 block--login">
                <img src="{{ asset('build/images/logo.png') }}" alt="Logo de DiamConcept">

                <form method="post" class="p-4">
                    {% if error %}
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="mb-3 row justify-content-center">
                        <label for="username" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i>Nom
                            d'utilisateur</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" placeholder="email@example.com">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3 row justify-content-center">
                        <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"><i class="fas fa-lock mr-2"></i>Mot
                            de passe</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-5">
                            <input type="password" name="_password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="*************">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token"
                           value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}"
                    >
                    <div class="text-center mt-4">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                            Connexion
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

What is wrong in my code ?
The authenticator seems to work because when the credentials are bad, an error is well displayed but when they're good, Symfony doesn't really log in the user.

**EDIT**

It look like the session cookie is not well created.
I configured `framework.yaml` like this:

```yaml
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    session:
        handler_id: 'session.handler.native_file'
        save_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/sessions/%kernel.environment%'
```

After I tried to login, the `/var/sessions/dev/` directory contains 2 files:
the first one is empty, the second one contains:

```
_sf2_attributes|a:3:{s:18:"_csrf/authenticate";s:43:"CWST-C6j5QkWUJzQEDYzF7ammv4eNyS5UQGCnfjjP14";s:23:"_security.last_username";s:5:"admin";s:26:"_security.main.target_path";s:17:"http://localhost/";}_sf2_meta|a:3:{s:1:"u";i:1612342250;s:1:"c";i:1612342250;s:1:"l";s:1:"0";}
```

**EDIT 2**
My guard `App\Security\UserAuthenticator` contains:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\InvalidCsrfTokenException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\CsrfTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Authenticator\AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\PasswordAuthenticatedInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class UserAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator implements PasswordAuthenticatedInterface
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const LOGIN_ROUTE = 'login';

    private $entityManager;
    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;
    private $passwordEncoder;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
        $this->passwordEncoder = $passwordEncoder;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {
        return self::LOGIN_ROUTE === $request->attributes->get('_route')
            && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = [
            'username' => $request->request->get('_username'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('_password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['username']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['username' => $credentials['username']]);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException("Utilisateur \"{$credentials['username']}\" introuvable.");
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->passwordEncoder->isPasswordValid($user, $this->getPassword($credentials));
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('home'));
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }

    public function getPassword($credentials): ?string
    {
        return $credentials['password'];
    }
}
```

Comment: there **could** be at least the explanation that the login works fine, but you lose the cookie

Comment: What's in your Gard ? Does the `onAuthenticationSuccess` is called ? Isn't possible that the `lazy` in your firewall is the cause ?

Comment: @jona303 yes, `onAuthenticationSuccess` is called, i've added the Guard content in the post. I don't think that `lazy` is the cause. I think that Symfony doesn't save the auth cookie